# How to point subdomain to another subdomain using afraid.org and CloudFlare

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cloudflare

So I have one subdomain from afraid.org (let's call it `sub.afraid.org`) and one domain registered somewhere (`sub.domain.com`) using CloudFlare DNS with it.

What I want to do is point `sub.afraid.org` to `sub.domain.com`, not a redirect, but just point to it and load the same content is loaded in `sub.domain.com` but in `sub.afraid.org`

I tried to setup a new CNAME record in afraid.org like this: `sub.afraid.org CNAME sub.domain.com` and there's also a CNAME in my CloudFlare settings but for some reason CloudFlare says it's unable to resolve the address.

I also added the `sub.afraid.org` in my virtual host config to respond to the requests (in this case Nginx).

I've googled about this and seems to be possible to do, but the problem seems to be with the CloudFlare settings or something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because CloudFlare does not recognize `sub.afraid.org`.

I suggest you point `sub.afraid.org` to the server that hosts `sub.domain.com` directly and set up a virtual host for it.

Please see this doc [Can I CNAME a domain not on CloudFlare to a domain that is on CloudFlare?](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/24119242-Can-I-CNAME-a-domain-not-on-CloudFlare-to-a-domain-that-is-on-CloudFlare-)

Comment: so that would be an A record pointing to the real IP address of the host, right?

Comment: Yes, be sure to add a virtual host to the server too.

Comment: If you are using a web hosting service provided by a CloudFlare partner, your web hosting provider *might* be able to configure CloudFlare for `sub.afraid.org`.